# in manytomany association, benefit of creating list of associated items

Tags: database, jpa, many-to-many

When we have a Many to Many association between two tables, and we create entity java beans for these tables, what is the benefit to create a collection in each tables to reference the items associated to it.

for example, we have two tables `A` and `B` which are associated to each other with Many to Many way, and let `AB` the link table in database.

```
public class  A {
    ...

    List<B> ListBs;   // what is the benefit to create this list, the same question in class B.

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefits of it are clear, with [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html) there's the choice to have the `List` loaded with the entity itself instead of having to execute a separate query.

This however can be a bit dangerous if you don't manage the `LazyInitialization` properly. Not establishing it has the result of the whole `List` being fetched from DB each time you load an Entity. Also setting it to be lazily initized can bring several problems if you try to recover an item from the `List` once the `Session` is closed.

In conclussion, you have to manage this kind of associations carefully. Think about what your application needs to be loaded and fit your model to what you really need. If using *lazies* take care about realoading the object if previous `Session` has expired.